# How do I use a string conditional in a while loop, java?

Tags: java, string, while-loop

```
public class Diary {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter output = null;
        try {
            output = new PrintWriter (new FileOutputStream("diaryLog"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             System.out.println("File not found");
             System.exit(0);
        }

        //Ok, I will ask the date for you here:
        System.out.println("Enter the date as three integers separated by spaces (i.e mm dd yyyy):");
        int month = input.nextInt();
        int day = input.nextInt();
        int year = input.nextInt();

        //And print it in the file
        output.println("Date: " + month +"/" + day + "/" + year);
        System.out.println("Begin your entry:");
        String entry= input.next();
        while("end".equals(entry))
        {
        output.print(entry + " ");
        }

        output.close();
        System.out.println("End of program.");
       }
 }
```

The goal of this program is to take input and create a diary entry and output the input to a file when the word end is inputed. When I compile the program does not terminate when I input end and my diary entry is not saved in the output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the loop continues if the `entry` has value `end`. However you want the reverse of that so use `!` operator. Also you did not re-assign the `entry` with a new value within loop, so if the first value for entry is itself `end` it will result into infinite loop.

You need to re-assign value to `entry`:

```
String entry;
while(!"end".equals(entry = input.next())) {// I had used `!` logical operator
    output.print(entry + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On each iteration of the loop, you want to task the user for more input.  Because you want to ask the user to enter something at least once, you should use a `do-while` loop, for example...

```
String entry = null;
do {
    entry = input.nextLine();
} while (!"end".equals(entry));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of changes to be made. What you should have is:

```
 String entry= input.next();
    output.print(entry + " ");
    while(! "end".equals(entry))
    {

        entry= input.next();
    }

    output.close();
    System.out.println("End of program.");
```

The intension is, while the user doen't enter 'end' continue reading.

Comment: Also remember to close input:    input.close();

Answer (score 0):

The solution given above is correct but don't forget to close your `input`.Otherwise in eclipse you will face Heap Size issue when you will try to open your text file.